# Sorting to match a given list

Tags: tex-core, sorting, comma-separated-list

I am looking for ideas on the following task. I want to sort the entries in `\listb` to those in `\lista`. It cannot always be assumed that only the elements of `\lista` are in `\listb`; neither can it be assumed that all the elements of `\lista` are in `\listb`.

```
\def\lista{a,b,c,d} % no 'e,f,g,h' in \lista
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b} % no 'd' in \listb
```

Here, I want `\listb` to be become `{a,b,c,e,h,f,g}`. Note: `e,h,f,g` in the resulting `\listb` should follow their 'partial ordering' in the original `\listb`, i.e., how they were ordered in original `\listb`.

Comment: Just that I got you correct: The order of the elements after sorting, which are not in lista, is of no importance to you? You just want every element of listb in the same order as they appeared in lista?

Comment: @DominikusK. Yes!

Comment: Just a micro nitpick: that's not partial ordering but rather *order of appearance*.

Comment: @percusse: You should have first asked how the actual set came about before giving it a name. *A familiar real-life example of a partially ordered set is the set of all street addresses in a town: 50 Maple St. is clearly "before" 52 Maple St. and "after" 48 Maple St., therefore all Maple St. addresses are ordered. Also, all Pine St. addresses are ordered in the same way. But you cannot tell if 50 Maple St. is "before" or "after" 300 Pine St. in this way, so any set that includes addresses on both streets is only partially ordered.* [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_ordering)

Comment: But even `e,h,f,g` qualifies as a poset: some pairs have the binary relation `<` while some don't.

Comment: What I meant is that we don't know if they are already ordered or not. So we don't need to assume any ordering partial or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

plain TeX (although would work in LaTeX of course)

```
\def\lista{a,b,c,d}
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b}

\def\x#1#2,{\ifx\relax#2\else
  \expandafter\let\csname #1-#2\endcsname\hbox
  \expandafter\x\expandafter#1\fi}
\def\y#1#2#3,{\ifx\relax#3\else
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #2-#3\endcsname#1,#3\fi
  \expandafter\y\expandafter#1\expandafter#2\fi}
\def\z#1,{}

\expandafter\x\expandafter a\lista,\relax,
\expandafter\x\expandafter b\listb,\relax,
\edef\listb{%
\expandafter\z\romannumeral`\x%
\expandafter\y\expandafter\hbox\expandafter b\lista,\relax,%
\expandafter\y\expandafter\relax\expandafter a\listb,\relax,}

\show\listb

\bye
```

---

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sort111.tex
> \listb=macro:
->a,b,c,e,h,f,g.
l.19 \show\listb

? 
 )
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Translation: Using `\x`, define two boolean arrays `a` and `b` indicating which letters are in `\lista` and `\listb`.  Then using `\y`, print each item of `\lista` that occurred in `b` followed by those items of `\listb` that did *not* occur in `a`.  I was going to propose this very algorithm but was discouraged by the difficulty of programming it.

Comment: @RyanReich yes (it's good to have self-documenting code:-)

Comment: Maybe your macro names could have been longer, but `\romannumeral` really said it all :)

Comment: Do I still owe you 10 bucks? `:)`

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I apologize for my newbie attempt.

Here's a humble idea I had with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\def\lista{a,b,c,d}
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ahmed_clist
\clist_map_inline:Nn \lista
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnT \listb { #1 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_ahmed_clist { #1 }
   }
 }
\clist_concat:NNN \listb \l_ahmed_clist \listb
\clist_remove_duplicates:N \listb
\ExplSyntaxOff

\texttt{\meaning\listb}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: My output]

Hope it somehow helps. `:)`

Comment: The trouble is that I don't know expl3, but I can guess what you've done. I was expecting a magic from David Carlisle or Bruno Le Floch.

Comment: @AhmedMusa not sure it's magic but 20 seconds after your comment....

Comment: @AhmedMusa: no worries. `:)` And David's answer is far more elegant! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is David Carlisle's solution. My only concern is the exponential rise in the number of defined controls, even with the garbage collector (local group) I have used.

```
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b} ->
  3601 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b,i,j,k} ->
  3607 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
```

I have generalized it to accept arbitrary list parsers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% \SortToMatchGivenList[<parser>]{<master list cmd>}{<user list cmd>}
\protected\def\SortToMatchGivenList{\@testopt\S@rtToMatchGivenList,}
\def\S@rtToMatchGivenList[#1]#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  % Define temporary macros of elements of master and user lists:
  \def\x##1##2#1{%
    \ifx\relax##2\else
      \expandafter\let\csname ##1-\detokenize{##2}\endcsname\noboundary
      \expandafter\x\expandafter##1%
    \fi
  }%
  % Insert elements of master list if they appear in the user list,
  % and insert elements of user list if they don't exist in master list:
  \def\y##1##2##3#1{%
    \ifx\relax##3\else
      \expandafter\ifx\csname ##2-\detokenize{##3}\endcsname##1#1##3\fi
      \expandafter\y\expandafter##1\expandafter##2%
    \fi
  }%
  % Gobble some remnant code when building the sorted user list:
  \def\z##1#1{}%
  \expandafter\x\expandafter a#2#1\relax#1%
  \expandafter\x\expandafter b#3#1\relax#1%
  \edef#3{%
    \expandafter\z\romannumeral`\x%
    \expandafter\y\expandafter\noboundary\expandafter b#2#1\relax#1%
    \expandafter\y\expandafter\relax\expandafter a#3#1\relax#1%
  }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#3{#3}}\x
}
\makeatother

\def\lista{a,b,c,d}
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b}
\SortToMatchGivenList\lista\listb
\show\listb

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

The following approach avoids defining a large number of temporary macros, but (like Paulo Cereda's) it is slower than David Carlisle's.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% \SortToMatchGivenList[<parser>]{<master list cmd>}{<user list cmd>}
\protected\def\SortToMatchGivenList{\@testopt\S@rtToMatchGivenList,}
\def\S@rtToMatchGivenList[#1]#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \def\tempe##1##2{%
    \def\do####1#1{%
      \ifx\do####1\else
        \if\relax\detokenize{####1}\relax
          \let\next\do
        \else
          \edef\next{\unexpanded{##2\do}}%
        \fi
        \expandafter\next
      \fi
    }%
    \expandafter\do##1#1\do#1%
  }%
  \def\tempc##1{\unexpanded\expandafter{##1}}%
  \def\tempd##1##2{%
    \@expandtwoargs\in@
    {#1\detokenize{##1}#1}{#1\detokenize\expandafter{##2}#1}%
  }%
  \def\tempa{}\def\tempb{}%
  \tempe{#2}{%
    \tempd{##1}{#3}%
    \ifin@
      \edef\tempa{%
        \tempc\tempa\ifx\tempa\@empty\else#1\fi
        \unexpanded{##1}}%
    \fi
  }%
  \tempe{#3}{%
    \tempd{##1}\tempa
    \ifin@\else
      \edef\tempb{%
        \tempc\tempb\ifx\tempb\@empty\else#1\fi
        \unexpanded{##1}%
      }%
    \fi
  }%
  \edef\tempa{\endgroup
    \edef\noexpand#3{%
      \noexpand\unexpanded{\tempc\tempa#1\tempc\tempb}%
    }%
  }%
  \tempa
}
\makeatother

\def\lista{a,b,c,d}
\def\listb{c,e,a,h,f,g,b}
\SortToMatchGivenList\lista\listb
\show\listb

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```